# Linux: How to rename old mysqld when upgrading MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-administration, percona

I'm upgrading MySQL from MySQL 5.0 to Percona Server 5.1.

I'm planning to just use `yum remove` and `yum install` to do the upgrade.

However, I read in the documentation that it's a good idea to rename the old `mysqld` to `mysqld-5.0`. And if the upgrade doesn't work, I could just revert back to the old version.

1. How exactly does this work? If I use `yum remove`, doesn't that mean the old `mysqld` is removed? So how do I rename it?
2. Where is `mysqld` located? How do I find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the mysqld will be removed when you do a `yum remove`. You could copy/hardlink the file with the new name before the removing, but since I guess there is more replaced with this update than just the mysql demon executable, I think the better way is to make sure you have a working backup of your data and configuration files before you start and do the `remove/install` thing the other way round when something goes wrong.

1. Renaming: `mv /path/to/mysqld /path/to/mysqld-5.0` or, if you want the hardlink instead, replace the `mv` with an `ln` command.
2. `which mysqld` should show you the path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what documenation you are refering to that simply says to "rename" the daemon, but very few distros make that as simple as typing in a new name. I think SvenW gave you generally the right procedure.

Sometimes a distro will make transition packages that help with the upgrade path when major things change like this, in which case you might be able to run both side by side, test everything, then remove the old packages. However this is up to your distro to provide. Either they bundle the software in such a way that nothing conflicts or they make one package obsolete/replace the other.